# Continuous function from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]$

Tags: gn.general-topology, tag-removed, real-analysis

Does there exist a continuous function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]$ such that $f$ takes every value in $[0,1]$ an infinite number of times?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes.  In fact, there exists such an $f$ taking every value *uncountably* many times.

Take a continuous surjection $g: [0, 1] \to [0, 1]^2$.  (Such things exist: they're space-filling curves.)  Then the composite $f$ of $g$ with first projection $[0, 1]^2 \to [0, 1]$ has the required property.

Comment: Great I didn't thought of that one, can I ask differentiability?

Comment: Yes and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volterra's_function is an example.

Comment: Is it obvious that these curve are continuous?

Comment: Space-filling curves, such as the Peano curve, are indeed continuous.  The existence a not-necessarily-continuous surjection from [0, 1] to [0, 1]^2 is much easier to prove --- it's just an argument about cardinality of sets.  Often one defines a space-filling curve as a uniform limit of a sequence of curves, and uses the fact that a uniform limit of continuous maps is continuous.

Answer (score 17):

Take a projection of a well-known Peano curve, which is a surjective continuous mapping $[0,1] \to [0,1]^2$ to a factor.

Comment: Snap          !

Comment: You are few seconds faster, Tom.